# Getting started with Hadoop and Eclipse

Tags: hadoop

I'm following a couple of tutorials for setting up Hadoop with Eclipse.

This one is from Cloudera : http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html
But this seems to focus on checking out the latest code from Hadoop and tweaking it. 
This is rare although, usually the latest release of Hadoop will suffice most users needs?

Whereas this tutorial seems to focus on setting up and running hadoop : 
http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html

I just want to run some basic map reduce jobs to get started. I don't think I should be using the latest code from Hadoop as cloudera specifies in above first link to get started ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [blog entry](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html) and [screencast](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2014/04/mapreduce-development-eclipse-screencast.html) on developing/debugging applications in Eclipse. The procedure works with most versions of Hadoop.

Comment: That entry just shows how to run a Hadoop job locally, for the purpose of debugging.  I believe @user470184 wants a way to submit jobs from Eclipse to a remote Hadoop cluster.

Comment: @Ken I don't think the question is regarding executing jobs on a cluster. It reads "I just want to run some basic map reduce jobs to get started". Any way lets wait to see if we can get some clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this tutorial on installing Hadoop plugin for eclipse: http://bigsonata.com/?p=168

Comment: can you please double check the link?